# C: How to modify the max size of a string in a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

The exercise gives a simple program to create databases, and this program turns around the following structure

```
struct Address {
  int id;
  int set;
  char name[MAX_DATA];
  char email[MAX_DATA];
};
```

I'm asked to modify the code so I can pass as an argument to the program the maximal length of  `.name` and `.email`. Now, of course, if instead of defining `MAX_DATA` as a macro I work with it as a global variable, I get the *error: variably modified 'name' at file scope*.

Then I tried to create different if-loops aiming to pass the MAX_DATA value by redefining`struct Address`, for example:

```
if(argc > 6) {
  int maxdata = atoi(argv[6]);
  struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[maxdata];
    char email[maxdata];
  };
  DatabaseSet(conn, id, argv[4], argv[5]);
  DatabaseWrite(conn);
  break;
}
```

but `DatabaseSet` and `DatabaseWrite` (which work on a `struct Connection` that relates to another `struct Database`, who finally relates directly to `struct Address`) ignore the new lengths of `name` and `email`.

EDIT: THANKS.

Thank you all for your comments and answers, your really helped me out with the exercise and with my general undestanding of C.

Comment: You can't have that sort of variability in the structure like that.  What you can do is use dynamic memory allocation for the strings (`malloc()` and friends; maybe `strdup()`), and store pointers to the dynamically allocated memory (`char *name;`) in the structure.

Comment: If no bound on the length of the name and email is known at compile time, then you cannot declare these members as arrays.  Make them poitners instead.

Comment: Depending on the full context, there may be no need for the `break` at the end of the `if`.

Comment: Note that if you are planning a database and are thinking you'll write copies of 'the structure' to a file, then you need to be rather careful. Using the fixed size arrays make that easy — each record is a fixed size. Using variable length arrays means you have to design how you'll know how much data to read, and therefore how to write the data, etc. Will you be able to do random access? This rapidly becomes a major exercise — aka a DBMS (albeit a fairly simple one, still). If you still have a fixed size (but the size might vary per file), you can store metadata (size of fields) at the top.

Comment: One of the terms to look for is 'serialization' (and deserialization).  Pointers in structures make serialization harder than having fixed size arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
  };
```

Then allocate memory dynamically in `name` and `email` based on your `MAXDATA` input.

Then you do this `struct Address p`.

And

```
p.name = malloc(MAXDATA);
if( p.name == NULL ){
   fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in memory allocation");
   exit(1);
}
```

and then when you are done working with it

```
free(p.name);
```

<sub>In case you allocate memory for `email` you will have to call `free()` on it the sane way as shown before.</sub>

Comment: don't forget to `free(p.email)`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons.: Yep that's implicated implicitly. I showed one set of actions for `name`.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that you also went more indepth with `p.name` in the malloc command, too.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons.: Added a note. Hope it's sufficient to help user